# Can Python multiprocessing be used on non custom functions

Tags: python, multiprocessing, networkx

I am trying to use multiprocessing to improve the speed of processing a graph of twitter followers. I found a handy built in [function](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable//auto_examples/algorithms/plot_parallel_betweenness.html) within networkx that lets you parallelize the betwenness centrality calculation.

I am trying to use the builtin clustering coefficient with networkx, but I am unable to get it working with the multiprocessing tools within Python, see code below:

`concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.map(nx.clustering,(DG))`

When I run this I get:

`results = super().map(partial(_process_chunk, fn),TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`

I'm guessing its not as simple as just using the multiprocessing methods and that a similar approach would have to be taken to the parallel betweeness centrality where I would need to divide the graph up into chunks and maybe create subsets to send to the processors.

Here is an excerpt from my code

```
import concurrent.futures
import csv
import networkx as nx


with open('nodes.csv', 'r') as nodecsv:  # Open the file
    nodereader = csv.reader(nodecsv)  # Read the csv
    # Retrieve the data (using Python list comprhension and list slicing to remove the header row)
    nodes = [n for n in nodereader][1:]

node_names = [n[0] for n in nodes]  # Get a list of only the node names

with open('edges.csv', 'r') as edgecsv:  # Open the file
    edgereader = csv.reader(edgecsv)  # Read the csv
    edges = [tuple(e) for e in edgereader][1:]  # Retrieve the data


DG = nx.DiGraph()
DG.add_nodes_from(node_names)
DG.add_edges_from(edges)


concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.map(nx.clustering,(DG))
```

Comment: Folks can't test their answers unless you provide a [mre] letting the error be reproduced.

Comment: Have you tested the excerpt to reproduce the problem when run without changes? (At a minimum, needing to create `nodes.csv` and `edges.csv` is a change you're currently leaving as an exercise for the reader; if the problem can be reproduced with two nodes and one edge, might be terser to start there -- with explicit code to create them -- and skip the CSV reading bits).

Comment: that said, in general: multiprocessing is indeed not a good choice for tasks where moving lots of data between workers is necessary.

Comment: You didn't instantiate a process pool executor object. You are trying to call the method directly from the class. Check out the docs